# Passlib in PyCharm doesn't allow to import anything from passlib.hash

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to `import passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha512` but for some reason I can only import the _proxy object.

I'm not sure why I can't import the particular module as it works perfectly fine when just launching a python shell from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Passlib developer here)

The problem is that `passlib.hash` does some lazy-importing tricks in order to load the hash classes on-demand instead of all at once (there's a lot of them, and most people only need one or two).  This wouldn't normally be a problem, but PyCharm's autocomplete seems to rely on source inspection rather than examining live objects... which means it falls down when the contents of a module aren't explicitly listed.

I've started using PyCharm myself, and I've tried tweaking how `passlib.hash` does things, but so far haven't found a way to trick PyCharm.  This thread (http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-54) seems to indicate this is a known issue w/ PyCharm, but it's from 2010, and I don't think anything has been done since.

If PyCharm ever adds a way for source to indicate that it's safe to live-inspect a module (e.g. by looking for some special marker comment in the source such as `# -*- live-inspection-safe -*-`), I'll be happy to add it into passlib.  Until then, this may be the state of things :(

---

**Update 2016-11-10**:

I sortof have a workaround for this.  Passlib 1.7's `passlib.hash` module now includes a list of all the imports that "could" be made, hidden inside an `if False:` block.  This seems sufficient to fool PyCharm into autodetecting the contents, without breaking the lazy-importing behavior.  Absent a better solution, this hack should hopefully work for now.